# SharePoint 2013: hover on search result automatically starts downloading document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, browsers

I have configured a search results webpart to show documents based on the search keywords.

As soon as I hover on any of the search result item, it automatically triggers download and asks weather to save the document or open it directly.

This issue is coming on IE(I checked it on IE10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to find the root cause of the problem but not the solution(Will update when I get to the solution).

As it is an intranet portal, IE has its default security settings to medium-low(It is medium for internet sites).

Under medium-low security settings **Allow Active-X filtering** is disabled. Enabling it solved the issue.

**PS:** You can get to the settings by clicking on TOOLS->INTERNET OPTIONS->SECURITY->LOCAL INTRANET.

**EDIT:** 
The cause for this issue is that a webpage display template was used and modified to show the documents as well which was forcing the preview iFrame to download the documents.

The fix for it is to use the documents display template and configure proper services to show the documents.